# password saved by default android Browser

Tags: android, security, browser, passwords

When I study about default browser in android, I see the password that saved by it does't encrypt.
Is it security threat?
Is there any way to an android application that reads these password and abused them (with respect to this is possible to read browser history)?
Is there any way to encrypt these passwords?

Update: I see the passwords saved in /data/data/com.android.browser/webview.db file.
Does cookies for default browser save in this file, too?
If it is true, the sites access to this file for read and write cookies, and then a malicious app that resides on a site, can be access to webview.db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password has to be available to the browser in plain text, since that is how it is sent to the target page. In Firefox for Android and many desktop browsers, there is an option to use a 'master password' to secure the whole database. This does not appear to be available in Chrome for Android, or the default browser.

At that point, you have to think about what your threat model is. Android is supposed to prevent apps from accessing each other data; if this is bug free you're protected from other apps. However, if someone seizes the Android device, and can unlock it, they can read the passwords just as you can. Full device encryption with an annoyingly long passphrase can help against that threat.

The same, I expect, applies to the history. However, all three browsers allow you to delete cookies and history through settings. While on the desktop Firefox this can be made automatic on exit, it cannot on the Android versions; it remains a manual operation.

Finally, all three allow you to open 'private' or 'incognito' tabs for which history and cookies are not retained. This may be a good option if your browsing activity is sensitive.

Peter Trei, CISSP

Comment: There's also the trivial answer-  if you want to keep your password secure, don't let ANY browser save it.